# What is USON package? Is it the same with UTDFN

Tags: packages

What is USON package? Is it the same as UTDFN (ultra thin dual flat no lead)?
What is the typical pin formation for 8-pin component?

1. 4 pin on 2 side?
2. 2 pin on 4 side?

What's the different with QFN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like SON and DFN refer to the same package. JEDEC documents like [this one](http://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/JESD75-5.pdf) talk about "SON/QFN", but on the whole JEDEC site I couldn't find one reference to "DFN".

On the other hand, among its [dozens of packages](http://www.linear.com/designtools/packaging) Linear Technology lists [DFN](http://www.linear.com/designtools/packaging/#DFN) and [QFN](http://www.linear.com/designtools/packaging/#TQFN), but there's no trace of SON.

JEDEC describes the USON as:

> The Plastic Ultra-Thin Small Outline No-lead Package(USON) is a rectangular
>   semiconductor package with metal terminals along two sides of the bottom of
>   the package. The terminals are either flush with bottom or protruding slightly
>   below bottom of package. The main body of the component is generally a
>   molded plastic.

So a SON package, having its terminals on two sides, is much like a DFN. So 4 pins on 2 sides would be SON/DFN. A QFN-12 may have 4\$\times\$3 terminals, but other configurations like 2 \$\times\$ (5 + 1) are also possible.

[image]
[image]

This may cause some confusion if we look at the following package:

[image]

which appears to be a DFN-16 and not a QFN-18.

Comment: http://www.mbedded.ninja/pcb-design/component-packages/son-component-package has more information on the DFN (SON) component package.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are 4 pin on 2 side with central thermal pad from what I have seen. Like a smaller version of WSON. I have seen them referred to as USON/UDFN. 
As regards QFN, not sure of the exact definition, though I think a QFN is usually larger/thicker, usually square and often with no thermal pad. 
[JEDEC](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/uson) is a useful reference for packages (log in needed), and here is a [TI](http://www.ti.com/sc/docs/psheets/industry_standard_term/industry_standard_term.html) page I find useful from time to time also.